# Smartest way to make php and mysql query to handle "multiple choice" in WHERE part

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which should handle user access to customer in specific countries. A user can have access to only one country, or have access to all countries or everything in between.

Something like this: (1 = access, 0 no access)

*The rest is multiple countries like CH, UK and more. But maybe with only one hit pr. country, so it was decided to be pooled together at some point. Not smart, but that it what it is.*

```
|----|----|----|----|----------|
| DK | DE | NO | SE | The rest |
|----|----|----|----|----------|
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |    0     |
| 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  |    0     |
| 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  |    0     |
| 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  |    0     |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  |    0     |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |    1     |
| 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |    0     |
| 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  |    0     |
|        ...                   |
|        ...                   |
|        ...                   |
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |    1     |
|----|----|----|----|----------|
```

Is there a smart way to easily type the query in php, so I don't have to make many if-sentences?
It doable with IF's, but very cumbersome write, and even more if changes needs to be made.

So I'm thinking there must be a better way to do this.

EDIT
hasAccess() return 1 or 0, depending on access or not. The following is that I want to optimize if possible.

```
        if (hasAccess('dk_kunde')) { //adgang til dk kunde
        if (hasAccess('no_kunde')) { //adgang til no
            if (hasAccess('sv_kunde')) { //adgang til se
                if (hasAccess('de_kunde')) { //adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'dk' OR land = 'n' OR land = 's' OR land = 'd' ";
                } else { //ikke adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'dk' OR land = 'n' OR land = 's' ";
                }
            } else {
                $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'dk' OR land = 'n' ";                    
            }
        } else { //ikke adgang til no
           if (hasAccess('sv_kunde')) {
                if (hasAccess('de_kunde')) { //adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'dk' OR land = 's' OR land = 'd' ";
                } else { //ikke adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'dk' OR land = 's' ";
                }
            } else { // ikke adgang til se
                if (hasAccess('de_kunde')) { //adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'dk' OR land = 'd' ";
                } else { //ikke adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'dk' "; 
                }
            }
        }
    } else { //ikke adgang til dk
        if (hasAccess('no_kunde')) { //adgang til no
            if (hasAccess('sv_kunde')) { //adgang til se
                if (hasAccess('de_kunde')) { //adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'n' OR land = 's' OR land = 'd' ";
                } else { //ikke adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'n' OR land = 's' ";
                }
            } else {
                if (hasAccess('de_kunde')) { //adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'n' OR land = 'd' ";
                } else { //ikke adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'n' ";
                }
            }
        } else { //ikke adgang til dk og no
            if (hasAccess('sv_kunde')) { //adgang til sv
                if (hasAccess('de_kunde')) { //adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 's' OR land = 'd' ";
                } else { //ikke adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 's' ";
                }
            } else {
                if (hasAccess('de_kunde')) { //adgang til de
                    $WHERELAND = "WHERE land = 'd' ";
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add at least the beginning of the PHP that you don't want to write as an example and you'll probably get a PHP answer. At first glance, I would replace this table with Redis/ReJSON if I were you but that's not what you're asking for.

Comment: I'll update the php code I have at the moment, into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a normalized database view and query on it as needed:

```
CREATE VIEW `users_countries` AS
SELECT id, 'DK' AS `country` FROM users WHERE `DK` = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'DE' AS `country` FROM users WHERE `DE` = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'NO' AS `country` FROM users WHERE `NO` = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'SE' AS `country` FROM users WHERE `SE` = 1 UNION ALL
...
```

Then you simply query on this view by user id and country, like:

```
SELECT id FROM `users_countries` WHERE id = 123 AND country = 'DE'
```

Comment: Or query by user id only and get a list of countries it has access to.

Comment: Problem is that the user don't know which country or customer he/she is attached to. The only country information is on the customer itself.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, then you just query on this view by user id, like SELECT id FROM `users_countries` WHERE id = 123

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, but I think we are talking past each other. I have a table for costumer, which holds a country record, I think this is pretty normalized. I also have a tabel for user access, which holds a record for each country (1 = access, 0 = no access). But I'm looking for a smart way to build the query, so the WHERE part is dynamical depending on which access the user has. In your SELECT I still have to have OR in the WHERE if the user has access to both DE and DK.

Comment: Eureka, I get that you where trying to have me do now. Just fiddling with, getting "the rest" to work also. Meaning countries where I have no country code to compare to. Maybe it needs to be a != instead...

Comment: I'm glad it helped. So if you think this answer solved your problem, please vote up and accept it. ;)

Comment: I'll do when I'm finished, but are having some problems with getting the query right for "the rest" group.